# For some values, jquery timeago is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

For some values, timeago is not working in firefox or chrome.

As these values are coming from same DB column, via iterated loop, there is no reason for this difference in behavior.

Here is example of two values for which it works & doesn't.

**Javascript**

```
jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
```

**HTML**

```
    <time class='timeago' datetime='Wed Dec 11 07:38:28 GMT 2013'>
        12/11/2013 
    </time>
Actual Output :- 9 days ago


    <time class='timeago' datetime='Thu Dec 19 10:36:53 GMT 2013'>
        12/19/2013 
    </time>
Actual Output :- 12 19 2013
```

Update:-
Changing `<time>` tag to `<abbr>` doesn't make any difference. It works for exactly same values as earlier.

Comment: It might be useful to add that you are (presumably) using the Visualforce UI framework in your question and/or tags.

Comment: @Jesse, It doesn't matter. Visualforce will be rendered as HTML code. I have added two columns (apex:Outputtext output, {!case1.LastModifiedDate} output) to highlight actual output of the Visalforce code which goes in Timeago tag.

Comment: HTML code may ultimately be rendered, but there is some [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) through the use of Visualforce that people who view your question might not be familiar with, especially if you don't mention it in your question and/or tags. And rather than posting the "HTML" that you posted, some true HTML examples using actual values that work or don't work, and a more detailed explanation of what happens when they don't work, will open your question up to be answered by a larger audience in a fashion that is more likely to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instructions](http://timeago.yarp.com/) for timeago suggest that you need to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for your timestamps:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>

<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
```

Also from the instructions:

> Are you concerned about time zone support? Don't be. Timeago handles this too. As long as your timestamps are in ISO 8601 format and include a full time zone designator (±hhmm), everything should work out of the box regardless of the time zone that your visitors live in.

I find it odd that it is working for you otherwise in some cases, but you should probably change your timestamp format and see if that resolves your problem.